# c# webBrowser.ReadyState will not achieve Complete state inside DocumentCompleted event?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my little c# project. 
I need to somehow navigate through a site, performing a few simple actions on each page. My solution to it was along the lines of this:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = webBrowser1.Document.GetItemById("next_page_button");
        button.InvokeMember("click");
        webBrowser1.Refresh();

        //here's my ugly solution which works

        do {} while (webBrowser1.ReadyState!=WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);

        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.webtest.com/page3");
        webBrowser1.Refresh();

        //same method of waiting for loading, causes endless loop this time

        do {} while (webBrowser1.ReadyState!=WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);

        var images = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
        //and then I do stuff with all them images..
```

So basically my program detects that the webBrowser loaded a page just fine the first time with that ugly while loop, but then, after the navigate() command it enters the second loop and never comes out of it. How come? 
I've checked and double checked everything in debug mode, going through every step.

I could use your advice on organizing this program better for sure. xD

Answer (score 0):

After two years i don't know it would help!!
but for others, the main thread is getting busy with your while loop so webbrowser object can not do anything, you need to implement this

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler((object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs arg) => 
{ 
/// do anything you want with webbrowser document.
})
```

or using

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

, this will make your main thread loop once and the webbrowser object load it's resources like javascripts files.